# Cannot use namespace inside razor view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have installed the nuget packages PagedList and PagedList.Mvc in my asp.net mvc application. I can use them inside the controller without any problem.

```
using PagedList;
using PagedList.Mvc;
```

However, I cannot use them in the view:

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
```

It gives the red squiggly lines with the following error -

> The type of namespace name 'PagedList' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help.

Comment: Two things: ensure the usings are at the top of the view file, and Clean + Build the application and see if the error still appears. Views can behave strangely at times

Comment: Yep the using statements are at the top of the file and I did a clean + build in the application. The error still appears.

Comment: Can you check your project's target framework/version as well as the supported frameworks of the `PagedList` package?

Comment: Check `Web.config` file inside Views directory to ensure `PagedList` and `PagedList.Mvc` namespaces/assembly references enlisted there. Sometimes Razor requires assembly reference to use namespace from DLL file other than local one.